# Codeigniter WHERE AND OR together

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, combinations, where-clause

I am trying to combine Where And OR in Codeigniter via code.

```
$this->db->where("id",1);
$this->db->where("status","live")->or_where("status","dead");
```

Appeared result is as query
 `where id=1 and status='live' OR status='dead'`
Whereas i need result for this query.
 `where id=1 and (status='live' OR status='dead');`

NOTE: Please don't give solution of string passed as parameter from where function. That's not fit into my code. I Just simplified my problem above.

Comment: Checkout documentation. http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/active_record.html

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just found solution, if it can help some one.

```
$this->db->where("id",1)->where("(status='live' OR status='dead')");
```

Comment: Is there something like that with variables instead? Adding $this->db->where("id",1)->where("(status=$variable OR status=$variable)"); is probably a huge mistake that would open a gate for SQL injection.

Comment: Yes, @TheNavigat This is huge mistake that would open a gate for SQL injection.

Answer (score 9):

you can use where_in() like this

```
$status_array = array('live','dead');
$this->db->where("id",1);
$this->db->where_in('status', $status_array);
```

Answer (score 1):

you just add ->group_start() and ->group_end()

```
$this->db->where("id",1);
$this->db->where("status","live")
->group_start()
->or_where("status","dead")
->group_end();
```

Comment: `group_start()` and `group_end()` is available only from CI 3.x, not available in 2.x.
If you try in 2.x, you'll get an error `Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysql_driver::group_start()` (adding here for future search benefit)