# Array to comma separated strings

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

This is the code (I'm using Codeigniter):

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar IN (?)';

$query = $this->db->query($sql, array($values));
```

So $values is an array of strings that I want to add in the SQL statement where the "?" is. When I try this I get an "Array to string conversion" error. Is there any way I can add the values of the $values array as comma separated strings into the SQL statement?

Comment: Try this: 
$query = $this->db->query($sql, implode(",",$values));

Comment: that adds them all as one string so it won't work

Comment: I need each value to be a separate string so it will work in the WHERE IN statement

Comment: What about this? Try : 
$query = $this->db->query($sql, $values );

Comment: that's an array to string conversion

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20866323/codeigniter-where-and-or-togather

Comment: I can't use that since i'm creating the query statement myself as a string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you use simple codeigniter way

```
$this->db->from('foo');
$this->db->where_in('bar',$values);
$query=$this->db->get();
```

This will produce what you exactly want

**Update**
If you are strict with your way  you need to produce the $sql this way

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM foo';
    if(is_array($values)&&sizeof($values)>0)
    {
        $sql.=' WHERE bar IN (';
        foreach($values as $key=>$value)
        {
            if($key==0)
            {
                $sql.='?';
            }
            else
            {
                $sql.=',?';
            }
        }
        $sql.=')';
    }       

    $query=$this->db->query($sql,$values);
```

Comment: i'm building the query statement myself, it's a complicated query with joins so I can't use that

Comment: I saw your updated answer, the problem is I have other placeholders besides the values array. Something like this `WHERE foo = ? AND bar IN (?)` and `$query=$this->db->query($sql, array($value1, $values));`

Comment: it will work if your $value1,$value in order.You need to produce `?`  and remember `?` will contain string not array.as example `$sql = 'SELECT * FROM foo where bar IN(?,?,?) and id=?`;`$query=$this->db->query($sql,array(1,2,3,4));` It will produce `SELECT * FROM foo where bar IN('1','2','3') and id='4'`

Comment: thanks your way worked, do you see the other answer with 2 upvotes? Do you know how I can get that way working with placeholders? It works without placeholders but when I use it with placeholders it escapes/adds slashes to the quotes that were added with implode

Comment: Other answer is not wrong that's why he got upvote.Unfortunately It does not meet your requirement. You need to produce `?` with the same number of your `$values` size. And you need to do it using `for loop` or `array_map` or `manually` or any other way.If you see my previous comment's example and update answer you will get some idea how you can do it.

Comment: Yea I already got it working with your way. The other answer also works but not for my code with placeholders because the quotes get escaped

Answer (score 2):

You should pass string with comma separated in query. for that use `implode` function of php.

Do like this:

```
$values = array('bar1', 'bar2', 'bar3');
$string = "'".implode("',", $values)."'";
```

Then pass string in the query,

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM foo WHERE bar IN ($string)';
$query = $this->db->query($sql);

echo '<pre>'; print_r($query->result_array());
```

You will data in $query variable.

Let me know for further help if needed.

Comment: This answer doesn't work with my code (with placeholders) because it's escaping the quotes and adding slashes

Comment: Can someone please help on this its something like same https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/820948/array-to-string-in-cosmosdb-using-sql-query.html